# Excel vba: Store Arrays in array, nested arrays, jagged array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have 3 arrays, each contains 3 ranges. I want to store those arrays in one array. I try to do the following:

```
 Function test()        
            Dim a() As Range
            Dim b() As Range
            Dim c() As Range
            a = getA(dataWorkbook)  'a(1)=Range(...), a(2)=Range(...), a(3)=Range(...)
            b = getB(dataWorkbook)
            c = getC(dataWorkbook)

            Dim allArrays(1 To 3) As Range
           ' allArrays(1) = a
           ' allArrays(2) = b
           ' allArrays(3) = c

            test="HELLO"
End Function
```

However if I uncomment lines with `allArrays` assignment, the function returns !VALUE instead of "HELLO". What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The values you are adding to `allArrays` are not of the `Range` type.

Comment: a, b and c are not of type range, but of type Array of range. allArrays expects Range variables, not arrays.

Comment: How should I declare it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to create a jagged array is by using a `Variant`:

```
Dim allArrays As Variant
ReDim allArrays(1 To 3)
'rest of code will work as intended
```

You can simplify your code and just use the `Array` function:

```
Dim allArrays As Variant
allArrays = Array(a, b, c)
```

although in this case `allArrays` will be 0-based rather than 1-based.

Comment: How would I access the elements -ranges? I tried `allArrays(1)(1)` and `allArrays(1, 1)`. I pass it to a function that expects `Range`. The former gives a `ByRef` error (passed type wasn't `Range`), the later `wrong number of dimensions` error.

Comment: @Ans you would use `allArrays(1)(1)`.  As far as the `ByRef` problem goes, you could just change the function so that it expects a `Variant` (this flexible type has a way of clearing up `ByRef` problems). If worse comes to worse, you could declare a range variable `R`, and then `Set R = allArrays(1)(1)` and pass `R` to the function.

Comment: Why does this mistake happens though? Doesn't it mean that something is wrong - otherwise the Range type would have been passed? And what is being passed if it's not Range?

Comment: What is passed is a `Range` *subtype* of a `Variant` type. It seems like a bug in the VBA language that it isn't good enough. If all of your range arrays (`a`,`b`,`c`) have the same length, you might want to load them into a 2-dimensional range array, but that would require loops to load rather than simple assignment statements.

Comment: What do you think of using user defined type instead? Something like `Type MyCollection rangeArr1() As Range, rangeArr2() As Range, rangeArr3() As Range End Type` and then passing `collectionVar.rangeArr1(1)` to the function? It works even without changing function's arguments to variants, but not sure if there are some underlying dangers, seems too easy.

Comment: Or using `New Collection`?

Comment: @Ans If it works, do it. I don't know of any dangers, I use collections all the time (although I don't usually don't wrap them in a type).